# the amount of people shown is still displaying as 0

Tags: c

In a train of cars, the first car is 10 feet long and all subsequent cars are 8 feet long. All
cars seat up to 4 people. Since each of these values is constant, please use the following
constants to store them:

#define FIRST_CAR_LENGTH 10

#define NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH 8

#define CAR_CAPACITY 4

For this program, the user will enter the total length of the track and the maximum length
of the trains for the track. It is assumed that the trains formed will be as long as possible.
For example, if the user enters 30 for the maximum length of the train, then the actual
trains will have three cars and be of length 26, since a four car train would exceed 30 feet.
Your program should calculate the number of people that can be supported on the track at
one time

```
#define FIRST_CAR_LENGTH 10
#define NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH 8
#define CAR_CAPACITY 4

int main()
{
    int i, N;


    printf("What is the Value for N?");
    scanf("%d",&N);

   for(i=0; i<N; i++)

   {
 int trackL,trainL,trainL2,NumOfCars,ActualTLength,trainCar_1,NumofCars,People,TrackAvail,LeftoverT,NumOfTrains;


    printf("What is the total length of the track, in feet?\n");
    scanf("%d",&trackL);

      TrackAvail=trackL/4;

printf("What is the maximum length of the train, in feet?\n");
    scanf("%d",&trainL);

NumofCars = (trainL-FIRST_CAR_LENGTH)/NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH;

NumofCars++;

ActualTLength=FIRST_CAR_LENGTH+(NumOfCars-1)*NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH;

NumOfTrains = TrackAvail/ ActualTLength;


People=NumOfCars*CAR_CAPACITY*NumOfTrains;

LeftoverT= trackL-ActualTLength;


    printf("Your ride can have at the most %d people \n",People);


   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger to step through the code line by line and examine the variables and control flow as it runs. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `TrackAvail=trackL/4;` What is that division for?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define FIRST_CAR_LENGTH 10
#define NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH 8
#define CAR_CAPACITY 4

int main()
{
    int i, N;


    printf("What is the Value for N?");
    scanf("%d",&N);

   for(i=0; i<N; i++)

   {
 int trackL,trainL,trainL2,NumOfCars,ActualTLength,trainCar_1,NumofCars,People,TrackAvail,LeftoverT,NumOfTrains;


    printf("What is the total length of the track, in feet?\n");
    scanf("%d",&trackL);

      TrackAvail=trackL/4;

printf("What is the maximum length of the train, in feet?\n");
    scanf("%d",&trainL);

NumofCars = (trainL-FIRST_CAR_LENGTH)/NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH;

NumofCars++;

ActualTLength=FIRST_CAR_LENGTH+(NumOfCars-1)*NORMAL_CAR_LENGTH;

NumOfTrains = TrackAvail/ ActualTLength;


People=NumofCars*CAR_CAPACITY*NumOfTrains;

LeftoverT= trackL-ActualTLength;


    printf("Your ride can have at the most %d people \n",People);


   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some context. What are your changes?

Comment: Num0fCars => NumofCars